# How to make rest assured parallel call while doing UI automation using selenium

Tags: multithreading, selenium-webdriver, rest-assured

I have UI automation script running using selenium webdriver. While selenium script is running, i also want to hit rest-assured call which might take more than 2 minute to provide the response. I do not want to pause UI automation during that time. What is the best way to achieve this ?

Sample code:

```
WebDriver driver;

driver.get("somewebsite");
driver.findElements().....

//API call
Response response = RestAssured.given()
.accept("application/json")
.body(validateDB.toString())
.when()
.log()
.all()
.post("query.json");

//UI automation
driver.findElements()...
```

I do not want to wait for api call to finish.

I tried with multi threading but did not get good example.

Comment: I believe eventually you're going to incorporate what you receive from API with what you see on UI. Otherwise you won't need to have that in one test. So how are you going then to use the result of API call and in which point of your test?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CompletableFuture it provides various methods like supplyAsync, runAsync, and thenApplyAsync for asynchronous programming. Below I have added an example with a sample api where you can test delay

We are using `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` method to execute an asynchronous API call using RestAssured. The API call requests a response from `https://hub.dummyapis.com/delay?seconds=20` URL with a 20 sec delay and returns a Response object. This call is executed on a separate thread and will not block the main thread, allowing the UI automation script to continue.

When you are ready to access the respsone from api , below command Waits for the API call to complete using apiCallFuture.get() method. This will block the main thread until the API call is complete and a response is returned.

```
apiCallFuture.get()
```

Full code

```
   WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://havenweb.org");
    driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
    System.out.println("UI Started");
    CompletableFuture<Response> apiCallFuture = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        System.out.println("Started API Code");
        Response response = RestAssured.given().accept("application/json").when()
            .get("https://hub.dummyapis.com/delay?seconds=20");
        System.out.println("done with api");
        return response;
    });
    driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
    System.out.println("Done with UI");
    driver.quit();
    //below will Wait for api response if it is not yet done ,otherwise will return response immediately
    System.out.println(apiCallFuture.get().body().prettyPrint());
```